# Почему при конвертации не ловится исключение, а вызывается системная ошибка?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Почему при конвертации не ловится исключение, а вызывается системная ошибка?

```
int n = 0;
int alfa = 255;
try
{
      n = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
}
catch(EConvertError &e){};
try
{
      alfa = StrToFloat(Edit2->Text);
}
catch(EConvertError &e){};
```

Comment: А где же trow, порождающее исключение?

Comment: Не нужен throw. StrToInt и так отлично все генерит.
Код случайно не с под отладчика запускается?

Comment: Попробуй запустить без отладчика(напрямую с папки например).

Comment: Спасибо, без отладчика всё запускается!

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!TryStrToInt(...))
   Application->MessageBoxA(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

```
    bool Err = false;
    double dValue;
    AnsiString s = "5.3";
    try
    {
        dValue = s.ToDouble();
    }
    catch(EConvertError&)
    {
        Err = true;
    }
    if(Err)
    {
        DecimalPoint = ',';
        OppositePoint = '.';
    }
    else
    {
        DecimalPoint = '.';
        OppositePoint = ',';
    }
```

Comment: Очень полезно рекомендовать менять системный разделитель. Особенно, если ещё код работает, припустим, с Экселем. Потом в выводе могут быть разделители в разнобой.
Но ещё я не уверен, что в с++ builder есть у AnsiString есть метод toString.
Много программируете в С++/CLI ?

Comment: Это из реальной C++Builder программы. Не всегда я имею право менять разделители на чужой машине. А эти преобразования только для внутреннего потребления. Чтобы человек и не замечал, с какими десятичными разделителями работает. Как привык.

Comment: Эти изменения вылезут боком, если будете погружать к примеру Excel/Word.